# how can you safely assemble and control 4 motors to a rapsberry pi

Tags: dc-motor

i am not an electronics expert, before i tried connecting 4 motors to a single motor driver and i think i fried my pi. Could you guys pls suggest a safe way to connect and control 4 motors to the rpi. Any help, link or guide could be useful. Thank you

Comment: You can use two DC motor driver modules to drive 4 DC motors. For newbies, I would recommend the TT130 3~6V toy DC motor and L298N DC motor driver module. There are a couple of newbie friendly L298N Q&A in this forum. You might also find the following EE SE Q&A useful: How to use motor drivers with H-bridge and PWM input, to control direction and speed of DC motors? Asked 1 year ago Active 3 months ago Viewed 1k times
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510755/how-to-use-motor-drivers-with-h-bridge-and-pwm-input-to-control-direction-and-s

Comment: thank you for your response, so if i'm gonna use two motors with a single L298N then i should power the motors with 4 AA batteries and power the driver with a 5V supply. That should be perfectly safe right?

Comment: You may like to read the following tutorial. Build a robot buggy - rpi.org projects
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/build-a-buggy/1. As I said earlier, there are many posts in this forum on how to use L298N. Just search "L298N" to find 100+ results.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy learning. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different motor drivers.

The ones I use with the Pi are

**L298N module**

Each driver can drive two DC motors or one stepper motor. The motor power can be 5-35 volts at up to a total of 2 amps.

**L9110S module**

Each driver can drive two DC motors or one stepper motor. The motor power can be 2.5-12 volts at up to a total of 0.8 amps.

**L293D chip**

Each chip can drive two DC motors or one stepper motor.  The motor power can be 5-36 volts at a total of up to 0.6 amps.

I'd suggest starting with a L9110S if possible.  It is hard to wire wrong.

Whatever you choose I suggest you post schematics and a photo of your wiring **before** you switch the power on.

Comment: thank you for your response, so should we control 4 motors with two different drivers? and how much battery supply should we provide to the driver, as in how many AA batteries. Sorry if the questions i ask don't sound professional, i'm just a high school trying to work on a project.

Comment: There is no need to use different motor drivers.  I'd use the same if possible.  The motor driver to use depends on the power requirements of the motors you plan to use.  You need sufficient batteries to supply the voltage and current needed for the motors etc. for the length of time you want them to run.

Comment: if i were to use two drivers i would need to supply 10V from my pi to the drivers right? is it safe to do so?

Comment: @coder - no, you should be providing the power for the motors from a separate source.

Comment: i mean for the driver, if we are gonna have 2 drivers then we need two 5V supplies to power the motor driver, which is take in a total of 10V

Comment: @coder you need to find a simple electricity tutorial and study what volts and amps and watts and resistance mean. It is not this site's job to explain such things.